# What are Doof's fund sources?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

Phineas and Ferb are always up to making something and their inventions always disappear in the most comical of ways. It is always caused by Doof's '-inators' in his endless pursuit to rule over the Tri-state Area and take revenge on his brother Roger.

***Where does Doof source his funds for making his '-inators'?***

Canon references only please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He gets money from his ex-wife, [Charlene](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Charlene_Doofenshmirtz). We learn in [*Finding Mary McGuffin*](https://phineasandferb.fandom.com/wiki/Finding_Mary_McGuffin/Transcript) that in addition to receiving a hefty alimony, he also places purchases of various "*-inators*" directly onto her personal tab with vendors. She doesn't seem to have noticed or possibly doesn't care.

> **Doofenshmirtz:** *You know, I may be an evil scientist, but it doesn't take a degree purchased from the Internet with your ex-wife's money, to know how special and important you are to me.*
> **Vanessa:** *That's so sweet.*
> **Doofenshmirtz:** *Well, I'd better run. I bought a used -inator today at the garage sale, and it's missing one small part.*

and

> **Owner:** *Alright, alright I'll talk. Okay, there's this guy. He comes in every week for a lab coat. He has me put everything on his ex-wife's tab. See, her address is on the bill.*

Comment: nice! Could you please also add in the episodes you took these lines from? Thanks!

Comment: @InfinityMilestone - The link is already there. They're from *Finding Mary McGuffin*.